# Why Rust Box in the for loop body doesn't free the memory

Tags: rust, memory-management

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut x = Box::new(12);
    let mut z = &x;
    for i in 0..100{
        println!("z is {}", *z);
        x = Box::new(i);
        z = &x;
    }
    println!("{}", *z);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

I'm confused Why error not happen, I think the `Box::new` should be freed after every loop;
but it works fine. hope someone give me some help for this.
Thanks.

Comment: `x` is scoped to `main`, not the loop body. Why would `x` go out of scope in the loop?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thanks, I think I have figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is rust being smart. Even though the broad rules of ownership don't allow this, rust knows you don't use `z` while `x` has been reassigned, so this passes the borrow checker. If you move the `println` down one line, you can see it now causes an error.

```rs
x = Box::new(i);
println!("z is {}", *z);
// cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
```

This also happens without the `Box`.

```rs
let mut x = 12;
let mut z = &x;
for i in 0..100 {
    println!("z is {}", *z);
    x = i;
    z = &x;
}
println!("{}", *z);
println!("{}", x);
```

The rust borrow checker assumes any for loop can run any number of times, including zero. However, it also assumes that the entire body of a for loop will always run as a unit, which means it knows exactly where `x` and `z` need to be used. Only `x`'s value needs to be used at `z = &x`, while `z`'s value is overwritten and therefore irrelevant.

Another thing that will make this not work is if the value of `z` has a `Drop` impl. Since plain references are dropped silently, there is no risk of the old `x` being used at `z = &x`.

Here's an example that *doesn't* work because `DropReference` has a `Drop` impl. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d727132b96f61661a370db16d0852a5a)

```rs
struct DropReference<'a>(&'a i32);

impl<'a> Drop for DropReference<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        dbg!(self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut x = 12;
    let mut z = DropReference(&x);
    for i in 0..100 {
        println!("z is {}", z.0);
        x = i;
        z = DropReference(&x);
    }
    println!("{}", z.0);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

This causes the following error:

```rs
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
12 |     let mut z = DropReference(&x);
   |                               -- borrow of `x` occurs here
...
15 |         x = i;
   |         ^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `x` occurs here
16 |         z = DropReference(&x);
   |         - borrow might be used here, when `z` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `DropReference`
```